# Taskbar Network "Repair" menu option gone in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I used to *LOVE* that feature in Windows XP!

Just right-clicked on the WiFi icon on the Taskbar (lower right-hand corner), then **Repair**.  It doesn't take that long, and it usually helped me since I constantly go back and forth between LAN at work, VPN on WiFi from work and home, and also VPN to my own personal server.  Even if you didn't need to refresh, doing so never hurts!

Unfortunately, the feature seems to be removed from Win7  :(  Now you can check for problems, but it only does the refresh if it thinks it needs too, and the whole process tasks so darn long!

**Is there a way to Repair my WiFi connection quickly and easily on Win7?**

Answer (score 1):

I am not a huge fan of that Repair option, basically what it did was disable the adapter and then renable it.  So you could just do that task yourself.  I agree, a single option is easier than the many more clicks this approach would take.

Comment: That is not entirely true. The Repair option visibly indicated to clear the ARP cache. Disabling and enabling the adapter may or may not do that (on XP I guess it didn't as some problems couldn't be fixed by dis/enabling it though that is anecdotal at best, I have no info in Win7, anecdotal or verified). In some cases clearing the ARP cache is useful, i.e. if you changed something in your network.